# laravel Error Composer Install in existe project

Tags: laravel

Whenever i do **composer-install **  in my laravel project i get this error
"In AdapterRepository.php line 65:
Expected name to be a non-empty string.**"

Any solution??

composer self-update --rollback
composer update
composer install
same error

Comment: Is there a file in your project named `AdapterRepository.php`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its composer install not composer-install try it and if failed remove the vendor folder and composer.lock and try again if it keeps failing replay my answer with the error
composer-install will through this error : The term 'composer-install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. If `composer-install` would do anything else than `composer install`, shouldn't it throw any other error?

Comment: composer-install will through this error : The term 'composer-install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it